Create hidden (screen reader only) text in PDF using Itext7 html pdf
I am trying to add text to my pdf that is only viewable to the screen reader. The pdf contains a table that converts negatives numbers, ie -4.565, to the (4.565) - red color. When I use a screen reader it just reads the 4.565 and I want to add negative before hand.
I have tried using aria-label, aria-live and creating a html property that is invisible due to text color etc

Have you tried the <title> element? It’s the intended means to provide an accessible title for a SVG, and it’s not shown.

I was under the impression that title could only be used with certain elements such as tables. Either way the solution I have now works. I also think that i tried title but it was not working with itext7, at least in the way I intended it to.

I figured out how to do it. I had to use convertToElements() instead of what I originally had which was convertToDocument().
Then you can recursively go through the element list until you find what description needs to changed and call .GetAccessibilityProperties().SetAlternativeDescription("Screen reader only") on the element. You also have to convert the element to its type first. (Paragraph)element.GetAccess...
    private string recurse(IList<iText.Layout.Element.IElement> elements, string previous, Document document)
    {
        string result = "";  
        // variable that get sent back that is the string of the content so that .SetAlternateDescription() can be called with the content

        foreach (iText.Layout.Element.IElement element in elements)
        {
            var elementType = element.GetType().Name;

            // I am only going through tables but it could be anything
            if (elementType == "Table")
            {
                Table table = (Table)element;
                IList<iText.Layout.Element.IElement> children = ((IAbstractElement)element).GetChildren();
                recurse(children, "Table", document); 
                document.Add(table);  
                // Add the most complex form, dont add children
            }
            else if (elementType == "Cell")
            {
                string content = recurse(((IAbstractElement)element).GetChildren(), "Cell", document);
                if (content.Length > 0)  // check to see that I need to set Description
                    ((Cell)element).GetAccessibilityProperties().SetAlternateDescription("SCREEN READER ONLY READS THIS STRING, NOT VISIBLE IN PDF:" + content);
            }
            else if (elementType == "Paragraph" && previous == "Cell")
            {
                result += recurse(((IAbstractElement)element).GetChildren(), "Cell-Paragraph", document); 
                // cell-paragraph to show the element came from a table -> paragraph and not div -> paragraph
            }
            else if (elementType == "Text" && previous == "Cell-Paragraph")
            {
                Text textElement = (Text)element;
                string content = textElement.GetText();
                return content;
                // This is where the actual string content is
            }
            else if(previous.Length == 0) // Add other elements, only when they are the parent element
            {
                Paragraph paragraphElement = element as Paragraph;
                if (paragraphElement != null)
                    document.Add(paragraphElement);
                Div divElement = element as Div;
                if (divElement != null)
                    document.Add(divElement);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

